# Trouble with Ralink RT-3290 on Debian : Works when it wants

Tags: debian, wifi

I am using debian stretch on some of my computer for about a month now. It works pretty well, but I have a problem when using my Hp DV6. Even if Ihave installed the wifi driver for my ralink rt-3290, (the firmware-ralink package) the wifi worked once, and after reboot is not available. sometimes, after five or six reboot it works for a time but stopped within hours. When I try to find the problem, the cards seems here and available, the correct driver is still working but wifi doesn't. 
I don't really know where to look for something else, and I didn't find any thread about that anywhere.

Please excuse my english, am not really fluent...

Comment: Welcome to U&L , which debian release ? Debian Stretch, jessie ...?

Comment: stretch, with non-free and firmware installed. It was the same with Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Install the `firmware-misc-nonfree` package

Comment: it's already installed

Comment: it's already installed, what is the difference between this and firmware-ralink ? they looks like they do the same jobs, could this make a conflict having both installed?

Comment: On debian stretch the ralink driver can be installed through the [`firmware-misc-nonfree`](https://packages.debian.org/fr/stretch/firmware-misc-nonfree) package , the `firmware-ralink` package is available for Jessie and prior

Comment: Ok, I tried to rm firmaware-ralink, but apt says firmware-misc-nonfree selected instead of firmware-ralink. autoremove change nothing, but I remember that problem was here before upgrading, and in ubuntu too (which is based on debian so it seems normal...) sorry for late answer